# vue.js: некорректно работает checked инпутов в фильтре

Tags: vue.js

Недавно взялся изучать vue.js и сделал простенький список дел. Список нормально отрисовывается, фильтр нормально фильтрует, но когда внутри примененного фильтра "Выполненные/Невыполненные задачи" меняешь статус задачи, происходит не то, чего я ожидаю: При нажатии на любой инпут, например "сходить в магазин", первая задача пропадает (переходит в "выполненные", это норм), но галочка (checked) ставится на следующий элемент.

Такое ощущение, что происходит конфликт нумерации элементов массива (с 0) и id задачи (с 1), но я не вижу где ошибка.

[Демо приложения](https://timesnewrouman.github.io/tasklist-vue/#/)

Task.vue - экземпляр задачи

```
<template>
  <li>
    <span v-bind:class="{ done: task.completed }">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        @change="task.completed = !task.completed"
        v-bind:checked="task.completed"
      />
      <strong>{{ index + 1 }}</strong>
      {{ task.title }}
    </span>
    <button class="remove" @click="$emit('remove-task', task.id)"></button>
  </li>
</template>
```

TaskList.vue - список задач

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <Task
        v-for="(task, i) of tasks"
        v-bind:task="task"
        v-bind:index="i"
        @remove-task="removeTask"
      />
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Main.vue - основной файл страницы

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <AddTask @add-task="addTask" />
    <select class="select" v-model="filter">
      <option value="all">Все задачи</option>
      <option value="completed">Выполненные задачи</option>
      <option value="not-completed">Невыполненные задачи</option>
    </select>
    <Loader v-if="loading" />
    <TaskList
      v-else-if="filteredTasks.length"
      v-bind:tasks="filteredTasks"
      @remove-task="removeTask"
    />
    <p v-else>Список пуст</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Настройка фильтра в Main.vue

```
  computed: {
    filteredTasks() {
      if (this.filter === "all") {
        return this.tasks;
      }

      if (this.filter === "completed") {
        return this.tasks.filter((tasks) => tasks.completed);
      }

      if (this.filter === "not-completed") {
        return this.tasks.filter((tasks) => !tasks.completed);
      }
    },
  },
```

Comment: Возьмите за правило, с циклом v-for всегда добавлять атрибут key  https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Да, ваше замечание, после некоторых манипуляций, привело к желаемому результату, благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге пришёл к такому варианту:

**Task.vue** и **TaskList.vue** объединил в один файл и прикрепил к v-for`у v-bind:key, как советовал добрый человек в комментариях.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="task in tasks" v-bind:task="task" v-bind:key="task.id">
        <span v-bind:class="{ done: task.completed }">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            @change="task.completed = !task.completed"
            v-bind:checked="task.completed"
          />
          <strong>{{ task.id }}</strong>
          {{ task.title }}
        </span>
        <button class="remove" @click="$emit('remove-task', task.id)"></button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```